# How the compiler decides the value and data type of variable b here?

Tags: c++

I am unable to understand how the memory allocation is working for variable b , is there some logic behind it or its just an another UB . The data type of b also becomes integer. \

```cpp
int a = 5,b;
cout<<b; // 16
```

Comment: value: Undefined Behaviour, type: `int`

Comment: It's up to the compiler, it can initialize it or leave it, in that case it has the value of whatever is currently present at the memory address.

Comment: The type is `int`, because that's the way variable declarations work.  Since `b` is not initialised, accessing its value (which is required to print the value) causes undefined behaviour.   When behaviour is undefined, the result could be printing of any value.   It could also be an immediate program crash without output, reformatting the hard drive, or (unlikely in practice) uninstalling windows from a system hard drive and installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare several variables of the same type in a single statement, where the variables are separated by commas. So, `b` is declared to be an `int`, and is uninitialized, so it has an indeterminate value, and using its value is undefined behavior.

The recommendation is to declare a single variable per statement, and to always initialize variables:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
std::cout << b;   // prints 0
```

In a single statement, that would be

```
int a = 5, b = 0;
std::cout << b;  // prints 0
```

Answer (score 3):

> How the compiler decides the value and data type of variable b here?

The compiler interprets the data type from the source code. You declared it as `int`, so that is the type.

You didn't provide any initialiser, so the value is indeterminate. When you read the indeterminate value upon inserting it to the character stream, the behaviour of the program is undefined. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard does not define what happens with this program: the behaviour on reading an uninitialised `int` is undefined.

If you want to examine the compiled program (to see what's going to happen), then look at the compiled program. Bear in mind though that what you see is only one possibility of many. Note that modern optimising compilers will often reason to themselves that `std::cout << b;` is not reachable as they are allowed to assume that there is no undefined branch, and compile out that branch altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote:

```
int a = 5,b;
```

The above statement means four things:

1. You're **defining** 2 variables named `a` and `b`.
2. The **type** of these variables is `int` because you've specified the type as `int`.
3. The variable `a` has been **initialized** with the **prvalue expression** `5`. This means that from this point onwards `a` holds the value `5`.
4. The variable `b` has **not** been **initialized**. This means that `b` holds an **indeterminate value**. This has an important consequence in your program. In particular, if/when you use this **uninitialized variable `b`** then it will result in **undefined behavior**. So when you wrote:

```
cout<<b;//this is undefined behavior
```

The above statement leads to **undefined behavior** because you're using the uninitialized variable `b`.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Solution

This is the reason it is advised that:

> always initialize built in types in local/block scope.

So you can **solve** this problem by initializing the vairalbe `b` as shown below:

```
int a = 5, b = 3; //initialize a with 5 and b with 3
std::cout << b;   //this is valid now
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: it doesnt hold a garbage value. From the point of view of the standard the value is indeterminate, it is just not possible to inspect the value in a valid program, ie it doesnt make sense to speak of the value of `b` to be any particular value. If you do read the value then it isnt garbage, but by looking at the output of the compiler one can see where the value comes from.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes indeterminate value is the correct phrase. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: fine. I have a slight aversion against the term "garbage" (only "random" is worse), because it obfuscates what actually happens. For example, in principle it isnt possible to tell the difference between a "good" `0` and a "garbage" `0` by only looking at the value, while one might be ok and the other undefined

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The technical term given in the standard is *indeterminate value* instead of *garbage value*. But i have seen experts like Dan Saks etc, using the term *garbage value* for uninitialized variable. So often i use the same term. Ofcourse just because someone says it doesn't make it technically correct.

Comment: nobody is perfect. Just because an expert does it, I don't have to agree ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes exactly. Just because someone famous(or expert in their field) says doesn't make it technically correct. For technical definition one have to refer to the official documentation. Also, I agree that the phrase/word *random value* is a much worse choice than *garbage value* in this context.

Comment: Clearly your aiming for an authoritative answer. To that end consider changing "this means that b holds an indeterminate value" to "this means that the value of b is indeterminate".

Comment: @Bathsheba I quote from the standard C++ documentation: *"When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object **has an indeterminate value**"*. So there is no need for the change you suggested.

Comment: It still doesn't mean it *holds* an indeterminate value though. On some chipsets the value is very well-defined indeed, but that does not bubble up to C++. It's your answer though - we are only trying to help. Which is what comments are for.

Comment: You don't understand. I'm not talking about C++ here, but what lies beneath. Let's not get silly. There is nothing at all wrong with the C++ standard wording.

Comment: Which is exactly why "this means that the value of b is indeterminate" is better wording. Then there's a bribe. If you change it, I'll upvote the answer. It's the best so far after all.

Answer (score -1):

when you define a local variable without assignment, the value of it is not certain because the memory of the variable is distributed in stack area, and the data in stack are rubbish value.

In my environment, the run result is 0;

Comment: Defining a local variable does not involve assignment.   The syntax `int a = 5` *initialises* `a`, it does not assign it.   The fact that an `=` sign is used is a property of the language, but - according to rules of the same language - initialisation as part of a variable definition is something distinct from assignment.